# Running container as daemon?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following Dockerfile, show should start the zookeeper when a container get launched:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

MAINTAINER Khinkali

COPY ["zookeeper*", "/usr/local/zookeeper/"]
RUN ["/bin/mkdir", "-p", "/var/lib/zookeeper/"]
COPY ["zoo.cfg", "/usr/local/zookeeper/conf/"]

ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start  

EXPOSE 2181
```

What I want is run the container in the background as daemon.

After build the image, I start the container as follow(the name of the images is zookeeper):

```
dockerizer@docker1:~/zookeeper$ docker run -d -p 2181 zookeeper 
3632584a1df907b82ec868bd47ebe3c4360a9a6cc28ef751205db85b67e6604c
dockerizer@docker1:~/zookeeper$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

As you can see, the container is not active running at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried getting the logs using `docker logs <container name/id>` or running the container without `-d` (e.g. using `docker run -it --rm -p 2181 zookeeper`)? Please edit your question to add the output of one of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run zookeeper in foreground because it is requested as so by docker. The Command/Entrypoint must be a foreground process.

So change:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
```

To:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
```